# Jersey consuming JSON on POST

Tags: java, rest, post, arraylist, jersey

I'm attempting to add a method to an existing Jersey Rest service to take a post of a list of objects.  It doesn't like the way I'm doing it, or I'm missing a dependency or something... any help is appreciated.

Service markup:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public boolean update(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, @FormParam("photos") ArrayList<UiPhoto> uiPhotos) {
```

Errors:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public boolean com.creo.services.PhotoService.update(java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList) at parameter at index 1
SEVERE: Method, public boolean com.creo.services.PhotoService.update(java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList), annotated with POST of resource, class com.creo.services.PhotoService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

This compiles, but a request to method on the service blows up with these errors.

Comment: Theres already a similar question.. [here][1] hope it helps..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14075657/2654259

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include the data type of ArrayList.

The following dummy example works provided you send the `Item` object in the body of the POST request encoded as JSON or XML.

```
@POST
@Path("/{shoppingListId}/additem")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response addItemToShoppingList(
        @PathParam("shoppingListId") String id, Item item) {

    String itemId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    item.setId(itemId);

    if (listNames.containsKey(id)) {

        if (listItems.get(id) != null) {
            listItems.get(id).add(item);
        } else {
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
            items.add(item);
            listItems.put(id, items);
        }
    } else {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }

    return Response.status(201).entity(item).build();
}
```

The object Item needs to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Item {

    String id;
    String name;
    String price;

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ArrayList, use UiPhoto[]. Hope it helps.