# How to use VBA to send a json file and parameters to a REST WebService

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-services, rest

I would like to use Excel/VBA to POST a json file and several parameters to a REST WebService. I managed to send the json file but I don't know how to include additional parametes. Is there a way to do this?

The VBA code I use looks like this:

> ```
> Dim URL As String, objHTTP As Object
>
> Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
> URL = "http://localhost:8080/services/data/"
> objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
> objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
> objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
> 'objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "id", "1234"
> objHTTP.Send json_table
> ```

As you see in the line which is commented out I tried to send the parameter as RequestHeader, but this also did not work.

I am also responsible for the WebService so that I can change the REST interface there. Using Java I would like to read the parameters by using @QueryParam("id") or similar.

I would not like to include the parameter inside the json "file" because its structure matches an entity I'm using.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075422/post-request-with-multiple-parameters-json-and-string-on-jackson-jersey-java). Maybe you should use `java` tag on this question?